# Compare Two File And Match Column One

Tags: text-processing

Compare two files if second file contains a domain which is not found in first file than add "Static" in second field.

File1:

```
cleanwatersaveslives.com      WordPress
blood-mate.com                CodeIgniter
brotex.com                    WordPress
```

File2:

```
brotex.com
blood-mate.com
cleanwatersaveslives.com
suhailacademy.com
damiastudioz.com              
support.techpublications.org  
techpublications.org          
tekstilworks.com
```

What i want to get is:

```
cleanwatersaveslives.com      WordPress
blood-mate.com                CodeIgniter
brotex.com                    WordPress
suhailacademy.com             Static
damiastudioz.com              Static
support.techpublications.org  Static
techpublications.org          Static
tekstilworks.com              Static
```

Comment: When i run 
`awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} NR==FNR {v[$1]=$2} {print $1, (v[$1] ? v[$1] : "static")}' dynamic userdomains | column -t`

It gives:


        blood-mate.com                CodeIgniter   Static

        brotex.com                        WordPress        Static

        suhailacademy.com             Static

        damiastudioz.com              Static

Comment: That's easy to fix but there is no `cleanwatersaveslives.com` in `file2` so why is that present in your output ? You said "compare" not "merge"... Run `awk 'NR==FNR {v[$1]=$2;next} {print $1, (v[$1] ? v[$1] : "static")}' file1 file2 | column -t`

Comment: It's added, mistakenly missed in file2.

Comment: Yes it's working thanks, i'll be careful next time.